# How to skip over an encrypted pdf file in a loop

Tags: java, itext

I'm using iText 5 at the moment as a library. How would I go about reading a pdf file in a loop and if encrypted, skipping that file from being processed? Or how would I go about identifying if a pdf file has been encrypted?

Comment: A few minutes of googling reveals that the library you are using provides a handy method called `isEncrypted` on the `PdfReader` class.  (http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfReader.html#isEncrypted() )

Comment: Thank you, I did not notice that earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered in using .isEncrypted, it is important to also have the bouncy castle or whichever encryptor api library is used to also be declared as an import such as import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;